# How to Grab Specific Objects within a Web Service

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, unrecognized-selector

I'm using the GitHub Job web service. Here is a link to the service:https://jobs.github.com/api

Now I'm able to retrieve all the data inside a specific url such as this one:

```
@"http://jobs.github.com/positions.json?description=python&location=new+york"
```

**I'm able to get ALL the json data with the following code:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

NSString *urlString = @"http://jobs.github.com/positions.json?description=python&location=new+york";

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

NSLog(@"%@", json);

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
```

}

Now this is fine, **but when I try to do this:**

```
 NSArray *items = [[NSArray alloc] init];
items = json[@"description"];
NSLog(@"%@", items);
```

I get SIGABRT and the error I receive is the following:

JobSearch[1249:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8a82930'

I'm confused because with all other web services I've used I'm able to do things like this, and "description"  should be an item that I should be able to grab. I don't seem to be getting anywhere...

All help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Your JSON is an array, not a dictionary.

Comment: So if I want to get the "description" or "location" object, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Look at the JSON. You get an array at the top level. Find the index within the array to get the dictionary you want. Then you can start accessing value from the dictionary using whatever keys you want.

Comment: Ah I see, so now I start getting the proper NSUIntegers and then access those objects using NSDictionary?

Answer (score 0):

First it doesn't make sense to `alloc/init` your array, because you're overwriting it immediately with the next line

```
NSArray *items = [[NSArray alloc] init];
items = json[@"description"];
```

Also, `JSONObjectWithData` returns on object of type `id`, but you're assigning it to an NSDictionary, which is an assumption that proves to be wrong.

```
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
```

Apparently the method is returning an array, hence calling `json[@"description"]` is invalid. You could try using this:

```
NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
NSString item = [json objectAtIndex:0];  // grab item from array
```

Without a guarantee it will work. I suggest to first check the kind of object returned, perhaps with `isKindOfClass`, to see if it is an NSDictionary or an Array.

Comment: So If I want to get a specific item using an array instead of a dictionary, and then displaying it?

Comment: See edited answer. You would need to make sure about the data being returned by the web service, so you can know how to manipulate that data.

Comment: Ok So I got a specific job from that string, but now what if I want to get a dictionary object of "description" and display that?